# How to properly pass array interface/type to a child component in TypeScript React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Good Day,

I'm a beginner in TS and I'm having trouble passing my array of type PeopleType from the App.tsx to a child component List.tsx . I made sure that the props that this child will receive is of PeopleType. Here are my definitions:

**TypeDefinitions.ts**

```
export type PersonType = {
name: string,
age: number,
url: string,
note?: string

}

export type PeopleType = PersonType[]
```

**App.tsx**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import List from './components/List'
import './App.css';
import AddToList from './components/AddToList';
import { PersonType, PeopleType } from './TypeDefinitions';


function App() {

  const [people, setPeople] = useState<PeopleType>([]);

  const [person, setPerson] = useState<PersonType>({
    name: "Chris",
    age: 3,
    url: "https://tenor.com/view/quby-quby-chan-cute-ok-okay-sign-gif-16999811",
    note: "Sleepy most of the time."

  });

  useEffect(() => {
    setPeople([...people, person]);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>List of stuff</h1>
      <List people={people} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**List.tsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import { PeopleType } from '../TypeDefinitions';


const List: React.FC<PeopleType> = (people) => {

    const renderList = (): JSX.Element[] | any => {
        console.log(people)
        return (
            <div></div>
        );
    }

    return (
        <ul>
            {renderList()}
        </ul>
    );

};

export default List;
```

I'm greeted with an error that says:

**Type '{ people: PeopleType; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & PeopleType & { children?: ReactNode; }'.**

I've found the passing the spread array works but it just passes the object(s) inside the array not the array itself which in my opinion defeats the purpose of having types. Any help is appreaciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React props is an object which has keys determined by those passed to the component instance. So you need a type which describes an object with one key named `people`.

```
import React from 'react';
import { PeopleType } from '../TypeDefinitions';

interface ListProps {
  people: PeopleType;
}

const List: React.FC<ListProps> = (props) => {

    const renderList = (): JSX.Element[] | any => {
        console.log(props.people)
        return (
            <div></div>
        );
    }

    return (
        <ul>
            {renderList()}
        </ul>
    );

};

export default List;
```

You also need to destructure `people` out of props if you want to use it without `props.people`. Your current example has just aliased the props object to the name `people`.

```
const List: React.FC<ListProps> = ({ people }) => { ... };
```

Comment: Since the questioner is new to typescript, maybe explain without the destructuring syntax. I found it hard to grasp it in one go with other concepts when I was learning typescript

Comment: Fair enough. The question made it seem as if they were expecting destructing, but I have have included both syntaxes for clarity's sake.